# Oracle PLSQL update table where in Associative Array?

Tags: plsql, associative-array, plsqldeveloper, oracle12c, where-in

I would like to, in a stored proc, update all the records that match an id. 
Now, this list of id, is being passed in as a table of varchar (Associative Array)..

```
CREATE TYPE varcharArray AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000) index by ...
```

and the proc declaration is something like

```
PROCEDURE testProc (p_IDs in varcharArray, p_Success out Number)
```

and the update statement in the proc

```
update testtable 
set col = 'val' 
where id in (select column_value from table(p_IDs);
```

This doesn't seem to work. So i had to do a loop in the array and update for each Id.

But i'd really like it to update using the where in clause.. Any help would be great.

PS: the id field is a number.

Comment: What does the "..." after your CREATE TYPE mean?

Comment: thats nothing, will update.

Comment: OK, then it isn't in fact an associative array, it is "nested table".  An associative array is a PL/SQL type where you specify the index type e.g. "index by pls_integer" or "index by varchar2(40)"

Comment: actually there is an index by. sorry about that. Updated in question.

Comment: But then the `create type` is wrong, because you cannot create an associative array in the database, you can only declare it in a PL/SQL block.

Comment: I've declared it in a package. The stored proc is in the same package.

Comment: Then remove the "index by" clause to make it a nested table, and ensure that the type is declared in the package spec rather than in the body.  Then it should work.

Comment: It is declared in the package spec and not in the body. Plus, i need it to be an associative array because i'm invoking it from .Net managed data access which supports Associative arrays but not udt.

Comment: In that case I think you will need to transfer the data from the associative array into a nested table and then query from that.

Comment: oh.. wow, could you please give me a snippet of that? You can probably add it to your answer, so that if it works, i can upvote.

Comment: for i in 1..assocarry.count loop nestedtable(i) := assocarray(i); end loop;

Comment: ok, thanks for that.. will try this too.. and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
create table testtable (col varchar2(10), id varchar2(1000));
insert into testtable values (null, 'AAA');
insert into testtable values (null, 'BBB');
insert into testtable values (null, 'CCC');
insert into testtable values (null, 'DDD');
commit;


create or replace PROCEDURE testProc (p_IDs in varcharArray) is
begin
update testtable
set col = 'val'
where id in (select column_value from table(p_IDs));
end;
/

exec testproc(p_ids=>varcharArray('AAA','DDD'));

SQL> select * from testtable;

COL        ID
---------- ----------
val        AAA
           BBB
           CCC
val        DDD
```

Comment: how about create table testtable (col varchar2(10), id number); 
is there a way to cast the varcharArray .. something like :

    where in (select to_number(column_value) from table(p_IDs))

Comment: oh, i was just guessing.. I didn't know that theres a to_number() cast. i'll try it out.